# Some comments being interpreted when using subfiles?

Tags: subfiles

I am writing my thesis using a college provided template which uses subfiles. I have was stuck for a few hours on an issue wherein some comments are being interpreted by the compiler when the `subfiles` package is used and a `subfile` is compiled.

For example, this is my main file named `Main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
%\end{document}
\subfile{Hello}
\end{document}
```

My `subfile` named `Hello.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass[Main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

When the compile the main file (`Main.tex`), there is no problem. But when I try to compile the `Hello.tex` file, the compilation fails with the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

When I remove the `\end{document}` comment in the main file, things are fine once again. Weirdly, there is no problem with other comments in the same place. Only an `\end{document}` comment seems to be interpreted.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subfiles.cls` works by reading the file given as document class option, but letting the `document` environment equivalent to the `comment` environment provided by `verbatim`. This environment reads its contents verbatim and it is delimited by the string `\end{verbatim}` (it's not completely correct, but it's not relevant) and percent characters are *standard* characters.

The `comment` environment implementation is quite easy: it does the same as `verbatim`, but when the latter prints a line, the former simply throws it out.

Thus "hiding" `\end{document}` behind a comment character serves no purpose.

In your case the `%\end{document}` line ends the implicit `comment` environment and `\subfile{Hello}` executes `\skip@preamble` which makes `\documentclass`, `\document` and `\enddocument` into no-ops. Thus `Hello world` is found when the check against paragraphs in the preamble is still active, because it's deactivated when the *real* `\document` command is executed, which here never is.

So, no `\end{document}` behind comments, sorry.